# Arduino ESP8266 - stack ERROR - ESPExceptionDecoder to debug - need help to find ERROR

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

i have one project that can ready compiled. The function is break on the hardware an i need help to finde the error. I am a beginner and ask for help. How can I narrow the error down?

Sketch:

- SIGNALESP.ino (https://github.com/HomeAutoUser/ERROR_search/tree/master/SIGNALESP)

Platform

- Hardware: AZDelivery NodeMCU Lua Amica Modul V2 ESP8266 ESP-12E
- Core Version: latest git
- Development Env: Arduino IDE
- Operating System: Windows

Settings in IDE

- Module: Nodemcu v1.0
- Flash Size: 4MB
- Flash Frequency: 40Mhz
- CPU Frequency: 80Mhz
- Upload Speed: 115200

Problem Description

```
15:54:11.662 -> Fatal exception 3(LoadStoreErrorCause):
15:54:11.662 -> epc1=0x4000e041, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x4024bcc2, depc=0x00000000
15:54:11.701 -> 
15:54:11.701 -> Exception (3):
15:54:11.701 -> epc1=0x4000e041 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x4024bcc2 depc=0x00000000
15:54:11.701 ->
15:54:11.701 -> >>>stack>>>
15:54:11.701 ->
15:54:11.701 -> ctx: cont
15:54:11.701 -> sp: 3ffffce0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01a0
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffe80:  00000000 00000019 4024bcaa 00000000
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffe90:  00000001 3fff16a4 00000000 000001ff
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffea0:  00000000 00000019 401003fc 0001687b
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffeb0:  00000000 00000000 00000001 4024bcaa
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffec0:  00000000 00000019 3fff1134 4020ef28
15:54:11.701 -> 3ffffed0:  ffffffff 3fffc6fc 00000001 4024bcaa
15:54:11.741 -> 3ffffee0:  00000001 00000000 3fff1134 4020efc2
15:54:11.741 -> 3ffffef0:  00000019 00000000 3fff1134 4020f09d
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff00:  40214e08 00000000 00001388 00000057
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff10:  4020f060 3ffef254 4024bcaa 4021104d
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff20:  3ffef10c 3ffef10c 3ffef254 40211275
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff30:  007a1200 3ffef10c 3ffeeec0 402019b9
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff40:  00000000 00000000 00000001 40100304
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff50:  3ffef10c 00000000 3fff1134 4020f130
15:54:11.741 -> 3fffff60:  3ffef10c 3ffef254 0000000d 3ffef115
15:54:11.781 -> 3fffff70:  3ffef10c 3ffef254 3ffeeec0 402027dd
15:54:11.781 -> 3fffff80:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffef728 3ffef768
15:54:11.781 -> 3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffef728 40202849
15:54:11.781 -> 3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffef728 40212b68
15:54:11.781 -> 3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8500 40101059
15:54:11.781 -> <<<stack<<<
15:54:11.781 -> 
15:54:11.781 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
15:54:11.781 -> 
15:54:11.781 -> load 0x4010f000, len 1392, room 16
15:54:11.821 -> tail 0
15:54:11.821 -> chksum 0xd0
15:54:11.821 -> csum 0xd0
15:54:11.821 -> v3d128e5c
15:54:11.821 -> ~ld
15:54:11.861 ->
```

ESPExceptionDecoder Debug

```
Exception 3: LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store
PC: 0x4000e041
EXCVADDR: 0x4024bcc2

Decoding stack results
0x401003fc: millis() at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_wiring.cpp line 188
0x4020ef28: ClientContext::_write_some() at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h line 514
0x4020efc2: ClientContext::_write_from_source(DataSource*) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h line 450
0x4020f09d: WiFiClient::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h line 364
0x4020f060: WiFiClient::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClient.cpp line 220
0x4021104d: Print::write(char const*) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\cores\esp8266/Print.h line 60
0x40211275: Print::println(char const*) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\cores\esp8266\Print.cpp line 129
0x402019b9: commands::HandleShortCommand() at D:\Temp\arduino_build_652018\sketch/commands.h line 363
0x40100304: ets_post(uint8, ETSSignal, ETSParam) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 160
0x4020f130: ClientContext::_consume(unsigned int) at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h line 557
0x402027dd: serialEvent() at E:\Programme\Rasberry - Projekt\Projekt_FHEM\_Arduino\Firmware_SIGNALDUINO\SIGNALDuino-dev-r332_cc1101_200113\___funktionstuechtig_ESP\SIGNALESP/SIGNALESP.ino line 591
0x40202849: loop() at E:\Programme\Rasberry - Projekt\Projekt_FHEM\_Arduino\Firmware_SIGNALDUINO\SIGNALDuino-dev-r332_cc1101_200113\___funktionstuechtig_ESP\SIGNALESP/SIGNALESP.ino line 470
0x40212b68: loop_wrapper() at D:\Eigene Dateien\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 180
```

Comment: Well it crashes somewhere related to either answering something via WiFi or a serial command in `commands::HandleShortCommand()`. What are you entering as input?

Comment: The input ist only a command like V or ? [link](https://github.com/RFD-FHEM/SIGNALDuino/blob/bc3331b2ea5c74e7f9f2f9f10a13c1d5faeed428/commands.h#L121)

Comment: exactly. What have you inputted? And what is your line end setting in the serial monitor?

Comment: I have to enter a V. If I look at the ESP with Netcat and type V, I get an answer. If I do the same with Putty Telnet (port 23), the stack comes :-(  
 
`V
V 3.4.0-dev SIGNALESP cc1101 (chip CC110 unknown) - compiled at Feb  8 2020 16:08:51
?
? Use one of V R t X S P C r W s x e
V
` With linebreak, but here ist it not view

Comment: I'm assuming you're taking the sketch from https://github.com/RFD-FHEM/SIGNALDuino and this issue is from you? (https://github.com/RFD-FHEM/RFFHEM/issues/795) Which ino file are you using exactly?

Comment: Right, here [link](https://github.com/HomeAutoUser/ERROR_search/tree/master/SIGNALESP) is the testcode. This code have one ino SIGNALESP.ino

So you can see all files.

Comment: Yes the error is reproducable with PuTTY. It has something to do with line endings and invalid / empty commands. E.g., using `ncat -v 192.168.1.135 23` and typing `V` it works, but with Putty there is a crash. With PuTTY configuration Terminal -> Local Line Ending: Force Off things are a bit better but still empty commands crash it. I'll have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that code like

```cpp
            MSG_PRINTLN(TXT_UNSUPPORTED1);
```

with

```cpp
#define MSG_PRINTLN(...) { MSG_PRINTER.println(__VA_ARGS__); }
```

and

```
static const char TXT_UNSUPPORTED1[]        PROGMEM = "Unsupported short command";
```

On the ESP8266 calls the `println()` function which accepts a `char*`, expected from RAM. However since the string here was put into flash and not RAM, this function will crash upon execution.

The fix is to use the `__FlashStringHelper` class which calls the correct `println()` overload and doesn't crash.

See PR https://github.com/HomeAutoUser/ERROR_search/pull/1 and https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html